# Error "could not execute batch command.[SQL: SQL not available]" after failed delete in NHibernate

Tags: sql, nhibernate

After I delete an entity related to another record, the following error appears due a constraint:

> The statement DELETE is in conflict with the constraint... &c.

I manage this error with the following code:

```
    Using transazione As ITransaction = sessione.BeginTransaction
        Try
            sessione.Delete(entity)
            transazione.Commit()
            Return True
        Catch ex As Exception
            transazione.Rollback()
            Return False
        End Try
    End Using
```

If I try to perform an UPDATE statement again, the very same error occurs again, even if I would no longer have performed the DELETE statement.

Can someone help me to understand where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Please read the [NHibernate reference's chapter on exception handling](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#manipulatingdata-exceptions), particularly the second paragraph:

> If the ISession throws an exception you should immediately rollback the transaction, call ISession.Close() and discard the ISession instance. Certain methods of ISession will not leave the session in a consistent state.

When you call Delete(), you register the object for deletion. When the exception occurs, it doesn't mean the session suddenly forgets your request to delete the object. Also, the call to Rollback() mainly issues a ROLLBACK statement to the database - it doesn't revert your loaded objects to their state before the transaction was started.

By keeping a session around after you have rollbacked a transaction, you run the risk of, in a later transaction, committing *some* of the changes made during the first transaction.

Answer (score 1):

on the referenced entity have you put a cascade rule about the deleting of main entity?

Usually, I'm working with Hibernate for Spring Framework but the guide line are the same.

Comment: No, I don't...neither in the mapping nor in the database (SQL Server 2008 R2). There is only a relation between the two tables in the DB